# How to lower wattage of circuit

Tags: batteries, resistors, basic, fan, watts

I want to power a computer fan from a 12v motorcycle battery.

Disregarding the motorcycle battery being 12.6 volts (not charging), lets say that it's a regulated constant voltage source of 12 volts.

The fan needs to be 12v driven where 0.58 Amps will be drawn.
It is a very old fan, and I can't find a datasheet. But it is exactly this one:
https://www.ebay.com/c/1472102822

Ohms law says that a 24 ohm resistor is good for 0.5 Amps or current. However, Ohms law also says that the power being drawn will be 6 Watts. Most resistors do **not** have this high of a power rating.

*How do I power my computer fan the right way without getting a high wattage? I am not looking forward to using bulky, high wattage resistors.*

Comment: Part number and link to datasheet of fan required. Please [edit] the information into your question and not buried in the comments. "*Ohm's law says that a 24 ohm resistor is good for 0.5 amps or current.*" No, it says that a 24 ohm resistor connected across a 12 V supply will cause a current of 0.5 A but you won't be doing that as you're proposing to have the fan in series with it.

Comment: Why won't I be doing that when I want to put a fan in series with it? What am I not understanding?

Comment: Because if you drop 12 V across the resistor there would be 0 V left for the fan.

Comment: 1) 10 W resistors do exist and using a resistor is the simplest solution but not the most elegant as indeed a lot of energy is wasted (turned into heat by the resistor). 2) A more elegant solution will be to use a **motor controller** which will switch the power to the motor on/off very fast, if the on and off time are equal, the motor will run at roughly 6 V and 1/4 of its power. I suggest looking for a ready made motor control module and make sure it can handle enough current. Building your own using a microcontroller (for example an Arduino board) and a motor driver is also an option.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yeah I know these types of resistors work, and my problem with them is exactly what you say. I am currently building a PCB with a microcontroller, so I could integrate a motor controller on that board. Since that seems like the best solution to me so far.

Comment: >>>   Why won't I be doing that when I want to put a fan in series with it? What am I not understanding? –     The fan IS a "resistor" of sorts.   So when you have the fan & resistor in series, the total resistance is something much higher.   (You won't be able to measure the fan "resistor" with an ohmmeter but the effect is real).  Using a resistor as you describe is pretty common and works just fine.  The catch is it will only work with one load... i.e. whatever resistor you use, another fan would probably require a different resistor to get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that ohm's law doesn't apply to a fan since the fan isn't a resistor. The fan takes what it needs in power. When I connect the fan to the 12V battery (which I just tested), the fans spins and draws the amount of current it needs.

If I want to turn the fan on or off using a microcontroller, I just need to switch the voltage supply to the fan. Nothing else, nothing more.

I hope I help someone else who stumbled upon this "problem"

Thanks commenters for your help!

Comment: Good. Don't forget to accept an answer - even your own - to indicate that the problem is solved, otherwise the system keeps bringing it up looking for a solution. You can upvote other answers that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You have linked to an eBay ad instead of a datasheet. The fan has four wires so it probably has a PWM speed control input on it and electronics to efficiently control the speed  without the high heat loss of a resistor.

Internally the fan **is not** a simple brushed motor but is a miniature brushless DC motor with a chip generating a three-phase supply to the coils. You will find plenty of reading material on the web explaining their operation.

*"No datasheet? No sale!"*

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't even see those PWM wires on the eBay ad. I already have the fan, but those PWM wires are missing... I'll start experimenting with that!

Comment: It's not exactly that one then!

Comment: Well, it certainly is, but the wires are soldered off. When I look at the solder pads where the PWM wires go, there used to be some wires soldered on. But they are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The fan you show is a 4-wire PC case fan. Very common, nothing special. Being 4-wire, it includes the ability to do PWM control. If you feed it a PWM signal the power will be reduced in proportion to the duty cycle.

Here's a link to how to make a PWM control using the venerable 555 IC: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/pulse-width-modulation.html

Another option is to use a 12V to 5V DC-DC step-down, and use a 5V fan instead. These tend run at lower current than 12V ones. This is a bit like your series resistor idea, but without the losses.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the 55 timer PWM control. I'll have a look at that! However, if it is too much of a hassle, I think I'll just buy a new 5V fan which does have a datasheet. Since I only need to turn it on and off.

Comment: You could run it with a car USB charger and USB cable.